# Correct javascript syntax to attach a string variable to a google analytics custom event

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, google-analytics

I've searched here and elsewhere for a solution to this, but haven't seen this exact problem addressed:
I'm trying to attach custom google analytics events to SOME html links on a javascript generated site (the site is here... http://www.girlguiding.org.uk/biggig/index.html). Each link is dynamically generated from an XML file. Links that should fire off an analytics event have an ANALYTICS attribute in the XML, with a unique label to describe the link. I'm trying to pass this attribute into the 'action' property of _gaq.push. Here's what I'm trying (and getting an 'Unexpected Identifier' error)...

```
$link.wrap('<a id="link' + linkId + '" href="' + linkString + '" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'external_link', '" + analyticsString + "']);return true;" target="_blank"/>');
```

I can see WHY I'm getting the error - the " before analyticsString makes it appear that the onclick value is ending. **EDIT** - I'm now not sure about why I'm getting this error - even when use the following...

```
$link.wrap('<a id="link' + linkId + '" href="' + linkString + '" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'external_link', 'analyticsString']);return true;" target="_blank"/>');
```

...I still get the same error. I should also point out that I have the google tracking code included in the head of the html document.

(BTW, analyticsString is set to the string in the ANALYTICS XML attribute). But what is the correct syntax to insert analyticsString, as a variable, into the _gaq.push? I've tried both single and double speech marks.

Comment: I think this is an escaping issue. It was the ' characters, not the " that was causing the problem. I'm not getting the error now. I guess I'll find out tomorrow if the analytics events are firing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a squote escaping issue... the single quotes in _gaq.push needed to be escaped because they're in a string, and there's a problem with quoting analyticsString as an argument.

Try

```
$link.wrap('<a id="link' + linkId + '" href="' + linkString + '" onclick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'external_link\', \'' + analyticsString + '\']);return true;" target="_blank"/>');
```

Comment: Yes, this was right - and the events are registering on google analytics!